# JavaScript concat two Map objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to concat two (or more) Map Objects to a Map like array concat?

```
var map1 = new Map([['breakfast', 'meal'], ['dinner', 'meal']]);
var map2 = new Map([['launch', 'meal'], ['dinner', 'meal']]);
var concatenated = map1.concat(map2);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest way I found was to convert maps to `key value pair array`, concat them and finally create a new map from result:

```
var map1 = new Map([['breakfast', 'meal'], ['dinner', 'meal']]);
var map2 = new Map([['launch', 'meal'], ['dinner', 'meal']]);
var concatenated = new Map([...map1].concat([...map2]));
```

Comment: A simple `new Map([...map1, ...map2])` works too

Comment: Getting error : `Type map is not an array type or a string type`

Comment: @tryingToLearn Which solution? Mine or vaultah's?
Share some code to see what's the problem